# Storm results visualization

Tags: visualization, apache-storm

I've spent hours to find the best way to visualize the results of my Storm system. It seems that there is an infinite combination of technologies and I'm getting completely lost.

I want to avoid the use of a database so from what I have understood my system should have the following features:

- a queuing message system (such as [Redis](http://redis.io/), Kafka, ActiveMQ,...) that could be connected to my bolts.
- a server that establishes a websocket connection with the browser and stream the messages to it.
- a javascript library that updates the front end in real-time.

Could you please correct me if I'm saying something wrong regarding the architecture? And I also would appreciate to know which combination of technologies is the best.

Comment: Redis is not a messaging system but a key value based storage. what exactly you are trying to achieve ? could you be bit more specific ?

Comment: @user2720864 you have basic messaging usage in redis with pub/sub support, you can even plug websockets on redis topics with nodejs for instance. So I believe it is a valid usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Lan said, your question is too wide.

For the minimal use I personnally use Redis and Storm together as redis can be used as a basic queue (beware of persistence problems with redis and clustering if you have to), a shared memory space for storm bolts/spouts (storing configuration, intermediate results...) and a basic message broker (pub/sub support), it also has very good performance in latency and throughput.

You can then use a "classic" backend to plug redis topics to websockets using for instance nodejs with sockjs and redis client, but there are far more solutions for this problematic in many languages.

For the front part, it should be defined by your server choice (for instance sockjs-client or socket.io with nodejs), as fallback strategies are embedded when websockets are not supported in browsers.

To conclude, the best architecture is the one that fits your usage, so it depends.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways. I recently built a demo using Apache Storm + Kafka. For visualization I used JQuery --> Node.js (for restful web service) --> Redis. This is just one example. There are so many other combinations that you can consider based on your use case.